# JavaScript Sorting Multidimensional JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have this JSON string:

```
{
"widgets":[
    {"column1":[
        {"weight":1, "bID":1, "hideMe":false, "collapse":false, "titleOf":"Test 1", "colorOf":"color-blue", "theFunction":"functionName"}, 
        {"weight":2, "bID":2, "hideMe":false, "collapse":false, "titleOf":"Test 2", "colorOf":"color-red", "theFunction":"functionName"}, 
        {"weight":3, "bID":3, "hideMe":false, "collapse":true, "titleOf":"Test 3", "colorOf":"color-yellow", "theFunction":"functionName"}
    ]},
    {"column2":[         
        {"weight":1, "bID":4, "hideMe":false, "collapse":false, "titleOf":"Test 4", "colorOf":"color-white", "theFunction":"functionName"}, 
        {"weight":3, "bID":5, "hideMe":false, "collapse":false, "titleOf":"Test 5", "colorOf":"color-green", "theFunction":"functionName"}, 
        {"weight":2, "bID":6, "hideMe":false, "collapse":true, "titleOf":"Test 6", "colorOf":"color-green", "theFunction":"functionName"}
    ]},
    {"column3":[
        {"weight":3, "bID":7, "hideMe":false, "collapse":false, "titleOf":"Test 7", "colorOf":"color-green", "theFunction":"functionName"}, 
        {"weight":2, "bID":8, "hideMe":false, "collapse":true, "titleOf":"Test 8", "colorOf":"color-yellow", "theFunction":"functionName"}, 
        {"weight":1, "bID":9, "hideMe":false, "collapse":false, "titleOf":"Test 9", "colorOf":"color-white", "theFunction":"functionName"}, 
    ]}
]}
```

if I do

```
alert(testJSON.widgets.length);
```

I get 3, however if I do

```
alert(testJSON.widgets.column1.length);
```

I get "testJSON.widgets.column3 is undefined" as an error.

What I am ultimately attempting to do is take each column1-3 and sort them by weight. Through something like

```
testJSON.widgets.column1.sort(function(a,b) { return parseFloat(a.weight) - parseFloat(b.weight) });
```

So I can then do a $.each() via jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be able to access like you mentioned, you need to lay it out like this:

```
{
"widgets": {
    "column1":[
        {"weight":1, "bID":1, "hideMe":false, "collapse":false, "titleOf":"Test 1", "colorOf":"color-blue", "theFunction":"functionName"},
        {"weight":2, "bID":2, "hideMe":false, "collapse":false, "titleOf":"Test 2", "colorOf":"color-red", "theFunction":"functionName"},
        {"weight":3, "bID":3, "hideMe":false, "collapse":true, "titleOf":"Test 3", "colorOf":"color-yellow", "theFunction":"functionName"}
    ],
    "column2":[
        {"weight":1, "bID":4, "hideMe":false, "collapse":false, "titleOf":"Test 4", "colorOf":"color-white", "theFunction":"functionName"},
        {"weight":3, "bID":5, "hideMe":false, "collapse":false, "titleOf":"Test 5", "colorOf":"color-green", "theFunction":"functionName"},
        {"weight":2, "bID":6, "hideMe":false, "collapse":true, "titleOf":"Test 6", "colorOf":"color-green", "theFunction":"functionName"}
    ],
    "column3":[
        {"weight":3, "bID":7, "hideMe":false, "collapse":false, "titleOf":"Test 7", "colorOf":"color-green", "theFunction":"functionName"},
        {"weight":2, "bID":8, "hideMe":false, "collapse":true, "titleOf":"Test 8", "colorOf":"color-yellow", "theFunction":"functionName"},
        {"weight":1, "bID":9, "hideMe":false, "collapse":false, "titleOf":"Test 9", "colorOf":"color-white", "theFunction":"functionName"},
    ]
    }
}
```

No need to wrap the columns in an array.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of:

```
alert(testJSON.widgets.column1.length);
```

use

```
alert(testJSON.widgets[0].column1.length);
```

"column1" is a property in the first of object of the array "testJSON.widgets"

Answer (score 2):

The "widgets" key contains an *array* of objects, so you need to specify an offset to grab the appropriate column.

```
testJSON.widgets[0].column1; // returns "column1" object

testJSON.widgets[0].column1.length; // returns 3
```

[**You can try it here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/sQBGS/)

I would suggest revising the schema such that instead of "columnX" it's just "column". That will simplify traversal since you already know the column number via the offset of the "widget", e.g.:

```
alert(testJSON.widgets[0].column.length); 
alert(testJSON.widgets[1].column.length);
```

[**Demo (new schema).**](http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/sQBGS/1/)

Answer (score 2):

You have arrays not objects.
Instead of `alert(testJSON.widgets.column1.length);` you should write  `alert(testJSON.widgets[0].length);`

Answer (score 2):

The reason why `testJSON.widgets.column1` is undefined is because `widgets` is an `Array`, and you're not accessing an array index.  You can access `testJSON.widgets[0].column1` instead, or restructure your JSON to look like this:

```
{
"widgets":{
    "column1":[
        {"weight":1, "bID":1, "hideMe":false, "collapse":false, "titleOf":"Test 1", "colorOf":"color-blue", "theFunction":"functionName"}, 
        {"weight":2, "bID":2, "hideMe":false, "collapse":false, "titleOf":"Test 2", "colorOf":"color-red", "theFunction":"functionName"}, 
        {"weight":3, "bID":3, "hideMe":false, "collapse":true, "titleOf":"Test 3", "colorOf":"color-yellow", "theFunction":"functionName"}
    ],
    "column2":[         
        {"weight":1, "bID":4, "hideMe":false, "collapse":false, "titleOf":"Test 4", "colorOf":"color-white", "theFunction":"functionName"}, 
        {"weight":3, "bID":5, "hideMe":false, "collapse":false, "titleOf":"Test 5", "colorOf":"color-green", "theFunction":"functionName"}, 
        {"weight":2, "bID":6, "hideMe":false, "collapse":true, "titleOf":"Test 6", "colorOf":"color-green", "theFunction":"functionName"}
    ],
    "column3":[
        {"weight":3, "bID":7, "hideMe":false, "collapse":false, "titleOf":"Test 7", "colorOf":"color-green", "theFunction":"functionName"}, 
        {"weight":2, "bID":8, "hideMe":false, "collapse":true, "titleOf":"Test 8", "colorOf":"color-yellow", "theFunction":"functionName"}, 
        {"weight":1, "bID":9, "hideMe":false, "collapse":false, "titleOf":"Test 9", "colorOf":"color-white", "theFunction":"functionName"}, 
    ]
}
```

**Update:**

Actually, I think what you *really* want is to have a "two-dimensional" array (actually an array of arrays); named columns cannot be conveniently accessed in a loop.  This would be a better structure for your needs:

```
{
    "widgets": [
        [
            {"weight":1, "bID":1, "hideMe":false, "collapse":false, "titleOf":"Test 1", "colorOf":"color-blue", "theFunction":"functionName"}, 
            {"weight":2, "bID":2, "hideMe":false, "collapse":false, "titleOf":"Test 2", "colorOf":"color-red", "theFunction":"functionName"}, 
            {"weight":3, "bID":3, "hideMe":false, "collapse":true, "titleOf":"Test 3", "colorOf":"color-yellow", "theFunction":"functionName"}
        ],
        [         
            {"weight":1, "bID":4, "hideMe":false, "collapse":false, "titleOf":"Test 4", "colorOf":"color-white", "theFunction":"functionName"}, 
            {"weight":3, "bID":5, "hideMe":false, "collapse":false, "titleOf":"Test 5", "colorOf":"color-green", "theFunction":"functionName"}, 
            {"weight":2, "bID":6, "hideMe":false, "collapse":true, "titleOf":"Test 6", "colorOf":"color-green", "theFunction":"functionName"}
        ],
        [
            {"weight":3, "bID":7, "hideMe":false, "collapse":false, "titleOf":"Test 7", "colorOf":"color-green", "theFunction":"functionName"}, 
            {"weight":2, "bID":8, "hideMe":false, "collapse":true, "titleOf":"Test 8", "colorOf":"color-yellow", "theFunction":"functionName"}, 
            {"weight":1, "bID":9, "hideMe":false, "collapse":false, "titleOf":"Test 9", "colorOf":"color-white", "theFunction":"functionName"}
        ]
    ]
}
```